# Title in a ContentPage doesn't change with navigation

Tags: maui

In my MAUI application, I have 2 `ContentPage`. The first displays a list of items (notice the title *Dictionaries*).

[image]

When I click on one item, I want to edit and go to another page. So, the code in this first page is

```cs
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(DictionaryEdit)}?DictionaryID={dictionary.ID}", true);
```

that redirects the user to a *DictionaryEdit* page and the application displays the item and allows the user to edit.

What makes me crazy is the title of the page. In the viewmodel for the *DictionaryEdit* page a have a property for the title

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
string? _pageTitle;
```

and I change the title in the viewmodel with the appropriate text (new for a new entry or edit for an existing item). In the `ContentPage` there is a binding for the title

```cs
Title="{Binding PageTitle}"
```

When I call the new `ContentPage`, the title is still the same as the page has called.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

### Update

I update the title in the ViewModel

```cs
public partial class DictionaryEditViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    string? _pageTitle;

    public DictionaryEditViewModel(LIUDatabase database)
    {
        this.database = database;

        PageTitle = "My title";
    }
}
```

Comment: And where do you write to the PageTitle to set the titel? Ex: PageTitle = $"Edit Dictionary {id}";

Comment: I have just updated the post.

Comment: It should work. Have you set the BindingContext in the view like BindingContext = new DictionaryEditViewModel(); Also I can see that you have not set DataType in xaml for the ViewModel. x:DataType="viewmodels:DictionaryEditViewModel"

Comment: @PeterWessberg The `x:Data` attribute is not required, that's used to enable compiled bindings. It just speeds up the resolution of the property that is bound to, but the binding still occurs during runtime - with the difference that the runtime already knows where to look for the value.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the problem, but failed to do so. Can you create a new project and try to reproduce the issue? Also, please include all *relevant* code that belongs to the page, so the XAML as well as its code-behind and the ViewModel.

Comment: @Julian I am aware but to debug a problem it is good to have it. Hence my remark.

Comment: @PeterWessberg It's always good to have it, just saying that it's not strictly needed, so it won't have an effect on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

The view:

```xml
<ContentPage
    x:Class="MauiTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MauiTest.ViewModels"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MauiTest.Views"
    Title="{Binding PageTitle}"
    x:DataType="viewmodels:TestViewModel"
    Background="White">
```

Code Behind

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    BindingContext = new TestViewModel();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

The viewModel:

```cs
public partial class TestViewModel : ObservableObject
{   
    [ObservableProperty]
    public string _pageTitle;

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        PageTitle = "My title";
    }
}
```

Comment: It works for me in the page but not when I open this page from `GoToAsync` from another page

Comment: I just tried it and it works for me. Could you update your code so we could see what it is you do?